# Something is deleting a console app. Why is it being deleted?

Tags: c#, powershell, smo

I need to learn how to use SMO within a C# program, so the first thing I did was start a new, console app and then began putting in the basics. I decided to make the app accept parameters so I can pass in things like usernames, logins, etc. As I work on it and build it I have a PowerShell window open where I can call the app, give it parameters or not, etc. But something weird is happening which I don't understand. Sometimes when I run the app in the PowerShell window, it's then deleted for some reason. Why is it doing that? I discovered it when it first gave me the following error message:

> Program 'SmoListLogins.exe' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1 + .\SmoListLogins.exe "MYCOMPANY\Rod"

My SmoListLogins.exe program isn't there. Naturally I can easily re-create it, but I don't understand why its being deleted.

So you can see what I'm working with, here's the source code. I took it from a MSDN article and have added a little bit:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
namespace SmoListLogins
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var userName = args[0];
                ListLogins(userName);
            }
            else
            {
                ListLogins();
            }
        }
        static private void ListLogins(string userName = "")
        {
            var userNamePassed = (userName != "");
            Server srv = new Server("YOURSQLINSTANCE");
            //Iterate through each database and display.   
            foreach (Database db in srv.Databases)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("========");
                Console.WriteLine("Login Mappings for the database: " + db.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                //Run the EnumLoginMappings method and return details of database user-login mappings to a DataTable object variable.   
                DataTable d;
                try
                {
                    d = db.EnumLoginMappings();
                    //Display the mapping information.   
                    foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows)
                    {
                        var userNameMatches = false;
                        var starting = true;
                        foreach (DataColumn c in r.Table.Columns)
                        {
                            if (!userNamePassed)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName + " = " + r[c]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (starting)
                                {
                                    starting = false;
                                    if (userName == r[c].ToString())
                                    {
                                        userNameMatches = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (userNameMatches)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName + " = " + r[c]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error processing database: {db.Name}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looks like PowerShell is deleting my command line program. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005569/looks-like-powershell-is-deleting-my-command-line-program-why)

Comment: I've tried to delete the other post, as it wasn't clear what I was asking. I hope this post is better worded.

Comment: So you're trying to run this EXE from the build directory, right?  Is it possible that it vanishes when you start a build and then doesn't get re-generated because of some build error?

Comment: Good question, I don't believe so. If I find it otherwise, I'll come back and let you know.

Comment: @adv12 I just tried it several times, making sure that a build wasn't going on. No build was involved. Now comes the interesting part. I opened File Explorer, right-mouse buttoned on the .exe file and set it to Read-Only. Then with File Explorer open and a PowerShell prompt opened to the same location I ran the .exe about 10 times. It ran fine. However, the next time I ran it the .exe just disappeared and I got that error. I watched it be deleted from File Explorer and the error message showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I now know what was deleting my executable. It wasn't something I thought of, so I'm sharing with everyone the answer. Today I got an email from our chief security officer, informing me that the program I wrote was being blocked by Symantec Endpoint Protection. In my testing I'd run my app over and over again. After a few iterations of that it would disappear. It didn't occur to me that it was our corporate AV that might be doing it. Now it looks as though that is exactly what was going on.

Thank you everyone for your input in trying to help me resolve this. I hope that if anyone else encounters this problem they might consider the possibility of their AV as the reason why the app they wrote disappears.